# Show that $a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1} > 0$ for all n ≥ 1 either converges or tends to $+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

The full problem is as follows

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1} > 0$ for all n ≥ 1. Prove that the sequence either converges or tends to $+\infty$.

For this problem I feel I need to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that the sequence either converges or tends to $+\infty$. However, I don't know how to show the sequence is bounded or unbounded. My main issue is I don't know what to consider $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be for the start of the sequence.

Comment: The condition is equivalently $a_{n+1}-a_n > a_n-a_{n-1}$ for all $n$

Comment: There are sequences with some negative numbers which tend to $-\infty$.  For example with $a_n=k-\log(n)$ you get $a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1}= \log\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)  > \log(1)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ for all $n$ then the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing and therefore convergent, since it is bounded below.

Otherwise $d = a_{N+1}  - a_N > 0$ for some index $N$. Since $a_{n+1}-a_n > a_n-a_{n-1}$ for all $n$ it follows that $a_{n+1}-a_n \ge d$ for all $n \ge N$, and therefore
$$
 a_n \ge a_N + (n-N) \cdot d
$$
for $n \ge N$, so that $a_n \to +\infty$.

*Remark:* The behavior of *nonnegative convex functions* $f$ on $[0, \infty)$ is similar: These are either decreasing, so that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, or they diverge to $+\infty$ for $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but this my attempt.

Let's rewrite the sequence as $a_{n+1}>2a_n-a_{n-1}\Longrightarrow a_{n+1}>a_n+(a_{n}-a_{n-1})$. There are two possibilities, one is $(a_n-a_{n-1})>0$, which implies $a_{n+1}>a_n$, which in turn implies the sequence is monotonically increasing, so it either goes to $+\infty$ or converges. The other possibility is $(a_n-a_{n-1})<0$, then that means that $a_{n+1}<a_n$, hence the sequence is monotonically decreasing, but since all the $a_n$ are positive reals, then it has to converge, and in that case, it converges to $0$.

Comment: No 2nd part is wrong.It can be oscillation too.

Comment: which part exactly?

Comment: $a_{n+1}<a_{n}$

Comment: You need to assume that for all $n$ not inductively.

Comment: Mmm I don't think so. We have the equation satisfied by the sequence and if $(a_n-a_{n-1})<0$, then from the equation $a_{n+1}<a_n$ is automatic.

Comment: Not necessarily, I guess let $a_{n+1}-a_{n}>a_{n}-a_{n-1}$, so you cannot do by induction as Take $a_n-a_{n-1}=-1$ and $ a_{n+1}-a_{n}=1$.Is that automatic?

Comment: Yes, after more thought, you are right. There can be oscillations.

Comment: The sequence can be decreasing everywhere, or increasing everywhere, or initially decreasing and then increasing. I would not call that “oscillation.”

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna steal AlvinL's observation as a lemma to construct the following proof for this theorem:

$\textit{Proof:}$ Let $T_{n} = a_{n} - a_{n-1}$. By Alvin L's lemma, we see that $\forall n > 1. T_{n + 1} > T_{n}$.

We know that $a_{n} = a_{0} + (a_{1} - a_{0}) + (a_{2} - a_{1}) + ... + (a_{n} - a_{n-1}) = a_{0} + \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i} - a_{i - 1}) = a_{0} + \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} (T_{i})$. Therefore, to consider whether $a_{n}$ converges, it is sufficient to examine whether the infinite sum $\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} (T_{i})$ coverges. We break the rest of the proof up into cases.

Case 1: $\forall n > 1. T_{n} < 0$.
This means the sum must converge, because if it didn't then there would be values of $n$ for which $a_{n}$ was negative, but we're assuming that all values of $a_{n}$ are positive.

Case 2: $\exists n > 1. T_{n} > 0$ (We will call this value of n "$n_{0}$").
In this case, $a_{n}$ always tends to $+\infty$. By induction with AlanL's lemma we can see that if $a > b$, then $T_{a} > T_{b}$. If we consider any $n > n_{0}$ we know that for any positive $\epsilon < T_{n_{0}}$ (which exists since $T_{n_{0}}$ is positive),

$T_{n} - 0 > T_{n_{0}} - 0 > \epsilon$,

meaning the sequence being summed over doesn't converge to $0$ and it must diverge. And given that the sequence of $a_{n}$ is positive, it must tend to +$\infty$.

Since the infinite sum either converges or tends to $+\infty$, so does the sequence of values. $\blacksquare$

I have no idea what Monotone Convergence Theorem is, so I'm sorry I can't help with that, but I suppose the problem-solving takeaway here is that parsing linear recurrences in terms of differences between sequential terms can be extremely helpful because you can then sum those differences to get values we care about, and knowing a relationship between the differences in the sum allows us to prove something about the sum and thus about the initial values we care about.

Comment: The “monotone convergence theorem“ states that a real sequence which is increasing and bounded above (or decreasing and bounded below) is convergent. You need that in Case 1 to prove that the sequence is convergent (compare the first paragraph in my answer).

Comment: Oh dear, please don't call it "my" lemma, it's just a basic observation.